# JSlider does not appear?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JSlider but it does not appear when I run the code. I also created a button, but that one shows. Also, do you know how to change the location of the two to the bottom left and right? Thanks!

Here is my code

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener, 
                                             KeyListener 
{
private CurlingStone[] stones;
private int stonenumber;

private Timer timer;
private int delay = 15;

private Button button;

private JSlider slider;

public Board()
{
    stones = new CurlingStone[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
            stones[i] = new CurlingStone(Color.yellow);
        else
            stones[i] =  new CurlingStone(Color.red);
    }
    stonenumber = 0;
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
```

this button appears

```
    button = new Button("Launch");
    add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);
```

but the slider does not, so over here I'm not sure what's wrong

```
    slider = new JSlider(1, 10, 1);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    add(slider);
    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{   
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 725);

    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 50);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(95, 95, 210, 210);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillOval(125, 125, 150, 150);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(155, 155, 90, 90);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillOval(185, 185, 30, 30);

    for(int i = 0; i <= stonenumber; i++)
    {
        stones[i].draw((Graphics2D) g);
    }

    if(stones[stonenumber].stoneX == 185 && 
       stones[stonenumber].stoneY == 600)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        ((Graphics2D)g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        g.drawLine(200, 600, 200 + stones[stonenumber].dirX*10, 530);
    }

    this.requestFocus();
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: *"I'm not sure what's wrong"* - neither are we - consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), although, I suspect that the fact that you are mixing heavy weight (AWT components) with light weight (Swing components) and you've broken the paint chain and disposed of a `Graphics` context you didn't create and are attempting to change the state of the UI from within the `paint` method are all working against you

Comment: Start by overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the responsibility is chained to super implementation.  Don't call `dispose` on a `Graphics` context you did not create and don't call `requestFocus` in the paint methods. Change `Button` to `JButton` (and update the import statements)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you! Sorry, I'm still new to this, but the slider has shown up. Do you know how to move them to a different location, like the bottom left? Thanks!

Comment: Without more context, personally, I'd use to components, one to do the custom painting, one to hold the other components, the wrap them both into a single container, maybe using a `BorderLayout`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok thanks! I will try it